# SQL- How to count number of Yes No

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm still new to SQL. I have a problem in counting the yes/no. SO this is the situation:-

From this query:-

```
SELECT
    A.User_Key, A.Updated_at, B.User_name, 
    CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(Updated_at) = 8 
            THEN 'YES' 
            ELSE 'NO' 
    END AS Submission, B.type
FROM
    dbo.User_Data A 
RIGHT JOIN
    dbo.User_Masters B ON A.User_key = B.id 
WHERE
    MONTH(Month_Date) = 7 AND Year(Month_Date) = 2021 
GROUP BY
    User_key, updated_at, b.User_name, B.type
```

The result of the query looks like this:

```
  User_Key      Updated_at     User_name     Submission     type  
     2          2021-08-12        Gina           YES        iPhone
     2          2021-07-18        Gina            NO        iPhone
     2          2021-08-09        Gina           YES        Android
     3          2021-08-12       James           YES        iPhone
```

My concern is, from the query above, I wanted to make a new query that can count the yes and no in the same field. Such as below.

```
 User_name     Submission      type  
     Gina        2 YES 1 NO    iPhone
     Gina        1 YES 1 NO    Android
     James       4 YES 3 NO    iPhone
```

Comment: This is not a good Idea to have YES and NO in one column.

Comment: How do you get `2 YES 1 NO` for `Gina` `iPhone` ?

Comment: The YES NO result were sorted from Updated_at column

Comment: Side note: best way to compare date columns is not to use functions `WHERE MONTH(Month_Date) = 7 AND Year(Month_Date) = 2021` but instead use a half-open interval `WHERE Month_Date >= 20210701 AND Month_Date < 20210801` this allows indexes to be used

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_name, type, 
       CONVERT(varchar(12), count(case when type = 'YES' then 1 else 0 end)) + ' YES' 
     + CONVERT(varchar(12), count(case when type = 'NO' then 1 else 0 end)) +  ' No  ' as Submission
from (YOUR QUERY) q    
group by user_name, type
```

Comment: The query is succeed but seems like  the YES/NO didn't sort by ```updated_at``` but it sorted by ```type``` instead

Comment: @Mir Can you not just edit the script they have given you to sort as you require?  This is not a particularly difficult amendment on your part...

Comment: You want `sum()` not `count()`.  Otherwise, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak your query.  I would put the "yes"/"no" values in separate columns.  I think this is the query you want:

```
SELECT ud.User_Key, ud.Updated_at, um.User_name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ud.Updated_at) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_yes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(ud.Updated_at) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_no,
      um.type
FROM dbo.User_Masters um LEFT JOIN
     dbo.User_Data ud
     ON um.User_key = ud.id 
WHERE MONTH(Month_Date) = 7 AND Year(Month_Date) = 2021 
GROUP BY ud.User_key, ud.updated_at, um.User_name;
```

Note the use of *meaningful* table aliases rather than arbitrary letters.  This is important so it is simpler to read queries.